# Игнорирование размера кнопок

Tags: java, android

У меня есть две `ImageButton` кнопки

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"> // oval_button_off
    <solid android:color="#EE3D3C3C" />
    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp"
        android:topRightRadius="20dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="20dp" />

    <size android:height="15dp" android:width="15dp"> </size>

</shape>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"> // oval_button_on
    <solid android:color="#EEFFFFFF" />
    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp"
        android:topRightRadius="20dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="20dp" />

    <size android:height="20dp" android:width="20dp"> </size>

</shape>
```

и селектор к ним

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/oval_button_on"></item>
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/oval_button_off"></item>

</selector>
```

Если я в `onCreate()` делаю `button.setEnabled(true)` то  размер кнопки `20dp` а у всех `button12345.setEnabled(false)` кнопок `15dp`. Но если я делаю эти манипуляции вне `onCreate` то ничего не меняется

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.bNext:
                button.setEnabled(false) // размер остается тот же что был дан при onCreate() т.е 20dp, но должен стать 15dp
                break;
        }
    }
```

Как сделать так чтобы размер менялся

Comment: непосредственно менять размер button12345.setWidth() / setHeight()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Из документации к Shape#size](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape):

> Note: The shape scales to the size of the container View proportionate to the dimensions defined here, by default. When you use the shape in an ImageView, you can restrict scaling by setting the android:scaleType to "center".

То есть это не размер, это пропорции, согласно которым форма будет масштабироваться. Как заметил @Style-7 , лучшим решением будет изменять ширину и высоту самого `ImageButton`.